# Network interface settings on startup

Tags: raspbmc, wifi

I'm a total n00b when it comes to Raspberry Pi; I bought one yesterday and installed Raspbmc.

Everything is working quite well except for wifi. It's an old dongle using the Ralink 2571 chipset. I got it to an almost working state, but I'm missing the final step.

The dongle sees the networks immediately. I changed the settings through NetworkManager to use a static IP. I then ssh through the wired IP, and turn off the power saving mode (`iw wlan0 set power_save off`), unplug the wired network, and I get a pretty stable connection through wifi.

However, I haven't been able to make this change permanent. I've put `wireless-power off` in `/etc/network/interfaces` but it does nothing. I've changed `/usr/lib/pm-utils/power.d/wireless` to always set pm to "off", but it also does nothing. Then there's `settings.xml` for the NetworkManager add on, but I don't see any option to set power management there.

Short of putting some in a startup script, what can I do? For the startup script option, what would be the correct startup script?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved. I put the command in a script in `/etc/pm/power.d` which solved the problem.

Answer (score 1):

in /etc/network/interfaces, add this line after wlan0

`post-up iw wlan0 set power_save off`

Then reboot and see if the power_save status has been set properly

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! Unfortunately, that didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

As root I made an executable script in /etc/network/if-up.d named powersaveoff:

```
#!/bin/sh

# The connection is dropped when powersave if turned on.
# So we disable it.

# Check if the current interface is wlan0 otherwise exit.
[ "$IFACE" = "wlan0" ] || exit 0

# Disable the powersave
iw wlan0 set power_save off
```

Don't forget to `chmod 755` the script. 
After a reboot the power_save function is off. You can check it with:

```
sudo iw dev wlan0 get power_save
```

It should return:

```
Power save: off
```